# can't login to subway sufers with facebook

Tags: 8.0

I have been tuned to this beautiful game, but I can't login to it with my Facebook, even when network is good, it always reads, "password expire log out and login again", have done that severally, yet no response, please I need a 'bridge to Passover this river', what is the solution to this?